# Tax receipt sending to event registrants

Tags: civievent, cdn-tax-receipts

I have setup a golf tournament event.  It is using a financial type where I have set deductible=no (we want to issue tax receipts to registrants after the event when we know the true deductible amount).  So how is Civi still sending a tax receipt when people register? Note: it isn't happening every time someone registers, but it did happen when it never should have.

I looked at the event setup and can't see anything that would trigger a tax receipt being attached to the automated registration email.

Any ideas?  If the fintype is set to not issue receipts, I don't understand why a receipt would be issued for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

- Are ANY of the line items deductible? (Not just the contribution financial type)
- Is the setting "attach to workflows" set at administer - civicontribute - cdntax settings?
- Do you have any custom code implementing the eligibility hook?

Comment: Thanks - there is only one line item so I don't think that is it.  The "attach to workflows" is set to yes so that tax receipts go out automatically from our contribution pages, but the setting says it is for contribution pages, not event pages?  Our developer may have custom code in place, but I wouldn't know about that.

Comment: Yes you're right the attach to workflows wouldn't be for events. And just to double-check: Is it the official tax receipt being sent or is it that the event receipt message template has been customized to have wording that says it's a tax receipt?